# Why have Origin and Referer headers when Referer has enough information?

Tags: http, http-referer

If the Referer header has the Origin in it anyway, what is the point of having both?

If the server receiving an HTTP request wants to know the Origin, it can just look at the domain in the Referer header.

I understand that the Referer header is not sent if it's an HTTPS to HTTP request (and many other scenarios), but **why didn't they design it** so that instead of removing it, it was still sent, but it only had the domain name (which the Origin header would have)?

Comment: There are more scenarios when referrers are not sent - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy - and *changing* the behavior of an *existing* header is much riskier than adding a new one.

Comment: I'm not asking about why they don't change it, I'm asking "why didn't they design it..." in such a way to begin with.

Comment: The referrer header was invented long before cross-domain JavaScript calls were a thing. Same reasons horses weren't designed with airbags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Citing from here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158045/is-checking-the-referer-and-origin-headers-enough-to-prevent-csrf-provided-that

> In order to preserve privacy, any browser request can decide to omit
> the Referer header. So it is probably best to only check the Origin
> header. (In case you want to allow for users to preserve their
> privacy)
>
> The Origin header is null in some cases. Note that all of these
> requests are GET requests, which means they should not have any side
> effects.